# Codefresh allure report: Test reporter requires CF_BRANCH_TAG_NORMALIZED variable for upload files

Tags: automated-tests, pipeline, allure, reporters, codefresh

Set up:

1. Upon merge to master codefresh build job builds image and pushes it to docker registry
2. Codefresh test run job picks up new image and runs the test
3. By the end of test run CF job, allure report building step runs

Results:
3rd step fails with message in a title only if job ran all the way through pipeline
It passes fine if I rerun the job manually(no step 1, 2 are executed in this case)

Notes:
Manually adding that tag does not help

Test execution pipeline:

````
stages:
  - "clone"
  - "create"
  - "run"
  - "get_results"
  - "clean_up"

steps:
  clone:
      title: "Cloning repository"
      type: "git-clone"
      repo: "repo/repo"
      # CF_BRANCH value is auto set when pipeline is triggered
      revision: "${{CF_BRANCH}}"
      git: "github"
      stage: "clone"
  create:
      title: "Spin up ec2 server on aws"
      image: mesosphere/aws-cli
      working_directory: "${{clone}}" # Running command where code cloned
      commands:
        - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="${{AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}"
        - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="${{AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}"
        - export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="${{AWS_REGION}}"
        - aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name yourStackName --template-body file://cloudformation.yaml --parameters ParameterKey=keyName,ParameterValue=qaKeys
      stage: "create"
  run:
        title: "Wait for results"
        image: mesosphere/aws-cli
        working_directory: "${{clone}}" # Running command where code cloned
        commands:
          # wait for results in s3
          - apk update
          - apk upgrade
          - apk add bash
          - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="${{AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}"
          - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="${{AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}"
          - export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="${{AWS_REGION}}"
          - chmod +x ./wait-for-aws.sh
          - ./wait-for-aws.sh
          # copy results ojbects from s3
          - aws s3 cp s3://${S3_BUCKETNAME}/ ./ --recursive
          - cp -r -f ./_result_/allure-raw $CF_VOLUME_PATH/allure-results
          - cat test-result.txt
        stage: "run"
  get_results:
     title: Generate test reporting
     image: codefresh/cf-docker-test-reporting
     tag: "${{CF_BRANCH_TAG_NORMALIZED}}"
     working_directory: '${{CF_VOLUME_PATH}}/'
     environment:
       - BUCKET_NAME=yourName
       - CF_STORAGE_INTEGRATION=integrationName
     stage: "get_results"
  clean_up:
           title: "Remove cf stack and files from s3"
           image: mesosphere/aws-cli
           working_directory: "${{clone}}" # Running command where code cloned
           commands:
             # wait for results in s3
             - apk update
             - apk upgrade
             - apk add bash
             - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="${{AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}"
             - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="${{AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}"
             - export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="${{AWS_REGION}}"

             # delete stack
             - aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name stackName
             # remove all files from s3
             # - aws s3 rm s3://bucketName --recursive
           stage: "clean_up"```
````

Answer (score 0):

Adding CF_BRANCH_TAG_NORMALIZED as a tag won't help in that case.

CF_BRANCH_TAG_NORMALIZED needs to be set as an environment variable for this step.

Taking a look at the source code of codefresh/cf-docker-test-reporting,
https://github.com/codefresh-io/cf-docker-test-reporting/blob/master/config/index.js

```
env: {
            // bucketName - only bucket name, with out subdir path
            bucketName: ConfigUtils.getBucketName(),
            // bucketSubPath - parsed path to sub folder inside bucket
            bucketSubPath: ConfigUtils.getBucketSubPath(),
            // originBucketName - origin value that can contain subdir need to use it in some cases
            originBucketName: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
            apiKey: process.env.CF_API_KEY,
            buildId: process.env.CF_BUILD_ID,
            volumePath: process.env.CF_VOLUME_PATH,
            branchNormalized: process.env.CF_BRANCH_TAG_NORMALIZED,
            storageIntegration: process.env.CF_STORAGE_INTEGRATION,
            logLevel: logLevelsMap[process.env.REPORT_LOGGING_LEVEL] || INFO,
            sourceReportFolderName: (allureDir || 'allure-results').trim(),
            reportDir: ((reportDir || '').trim()) || undefined,
            reportIndexFile: ((reportIndexFile || '').trim()) || undefined,
            reportWrapDir: _.isNumber(reportWrapDir) ? String(reportWrapDir) : '',
            reportType: _.isString(reportType) ? reportType.replace(/[<>]/g, 'hackDetected') : 'default',
            allureDir,
            clearTestReport
        },
```

you can see that CF_BRANCH_TAG_NORMALIZED is taken directly from the environment.

My assumption is that whatever triggers your build normally will not set this environment variable. It is usually set automatically when you have a git trigger e.g. from Github.
When you start your pipeline manually you probably set the variable and that's why it's running then.

You should check how your pipelines are usually triggered and if the variable is set (automatically or manually).

Here's some more documentation about these variables:
https://codefresh.io/docs/docs/codefresh-yaml/variables/#system-provided-variables